# Безопасная проверка пароля

Tags: md5, password-hash

Подскажите, как сейчас с тенденциями проверки паролей. Еще достаточно надежно проверять подлинность пароля по двум случайным строкам, от сервера и клиента, и паролю, пропущенным через функцию md5?

Есть скрипт на php, он запрашивает у второго сервера id и строку 32 байта. После чего посылает запрос и подтверждение пароля в виде md5(str_serv, str_cli, pass, str_cli, str_serv, crc = md5(тело запроса));

Все строки 32 байта. Сервер генерит id и строку на лету и хранит их в памяти. Запросы в формате json. php скрипт хранит id и строку в файле, сервер хранит их 2 минуты.

Достаточно ли надежен такой способ проверки пароля?

А вот в ответе даже банального crc нет. Нужно ли добавить тот же алгоритм подтверждения пароля в ответ сервера?

Comment: Способ проверки пароля в вопросе не раскрыт, поясните пожалуйста. Также не очень понятен механизм аутентификации. Как я понял серверов два. Запрос на проверку пароля клиент отправляет первому серверу? Что получает в ответ? Для чего вы бы хотели crc со стороны сервера?

Comment: Нет, клиент и сервер. Пароль передается не в открытом виде, а как результат md5(...). Клиент шлет запрос, если пароль неверен сервер шлет ответ {"error":"PASSFAIL", ...} с новым id и строкой, после чего клиент посылает запрос заново. Если сервер проверяет crc и пароль клиента, то клиент, не проверяет ничего и это может привести к перехвату запроса и посылки абсолютно любого поддельного ответа.

Answer (score 1):

1. В вашей схеме используется *MD5*, который уже имеет коллизии и теоретически подвержен перебору (и вычислительные мощности постепенно растут) с другой стороны для данного случая не факт, что у кого-то окажутся такие мощности для конкретно вашего вариата хеширования. В любом случае, если есть возможность стОит заменить *MD5* на что-то понадежнее (например *SHA256*);
2. В части протокола аутентификации схема слабовата (как вы верно замеили, нет возможности проверить тот-ли это сервер), но из реально сильного могу предложить только реализовать связь через *TLS* с проверкой серверного сертификата. В этом случае авторизацию клиента можете хоть по голому паролю проверять. Однако хранить на сервере пароль в открытом виде естественно нельзя. Необходимо применять [функции формирования ключа](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) (статья на английском), например scrypt (ну или хотя бы "соленые" хеши).